# How to scrap hidden data that it shows until you click a button from web with Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, jupyter-notebook, data-science

I'm looking to extract data from a webpage using Python's Selenium library. However, I'm facing a challenge because the webpage has multiple tables that are only displayed after clicking a button. As a result, when I attempt to extract data, only the first table that is displayed by default is being scraped.

I would like to scrap all the tables

Comment: Please provide what have you tried so far.

Comment: selenium allow you to click on elements. Also i recommend to follow the ids and class names of the tables you want. Also you can try using requests library to follow the href thaht the button redirects to.. Also provide more info to find a specific answer